# Android Emulator not launching app

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am working on an Android project and using Android emulator Nexus 4 with API 21. Whenever I try to execute my app, emulator console shows below log. After last step "Starting activity com.shashi.puzzlesudoku.Sudoku on device emulator-5554", it doesn't launch my app. It stops at this stage. I have tried to restart Eclipse/my computer but it did not solve the issue. I even tried to create new emulator but it did not help. Since it is not automatically loading my app, I am unable to run debugger.

```
[2014-11-14 08:04:46 - PuzzleSudoku] ------------------------------
[2014-11-14 08:04:46 - PuzzleSudoku] Android Launch!
[2014-11-14 08:04:46 - PuzzleSudoku] adb is running normally.
[2014-11-14 08:04:46 - PuzzleSudoku] Performing com.shashi.puzzlesudoku.Sudoku activity launch
[2014-11-14 08:04:46 - PuzzleSudoku] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'nexus4'
[2014-11-14 08:04:46 - PuzzleSudoku] Uploading PuzzleSudoku.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-11-14 08:04:48 - PuzzleSudoku] Installing PuzzleSudoku.apk...
[2014-11-14 08:05:51 - PuzzleSudoku] Success!
[2014-11-14 08:05:52 - PuzzleSudoku] Starting activity com.shashi.puzzlesudoku.Sudoku on device emulator-5554
```

Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.shashi.puzzlesudoku"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name=".Sudoku"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Could you find your app on emulator's launcher?

Comment: Can you show your app manifest? Maybe there is a problem!

Comment: I have added Manifest xml.

Comment: Andrew T.  Yes , i can see on emulator's app launcher and i can run from there  .But it should start automatically when i run the App by right clicking on the project . It used to work but after i created new emulator , it stopped launching itself automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's already running and you can't stop it for new launch. Try to to stop running app by DDMS (if you a using eclipse Windows/Open Perspective/DDMS) and run it again!

Comment: I checked in ddms but it do not shows there as running process.